# Converting data to actual timestamp - how to add the correct unit?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, unix

I have a pandas dataframe with such a timestamp:

```
1615860000
```

This is: Tue Mar 16 2021 02:00:00 GMT+0000

However, when I convert it to datetime using this code:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],utc=True).dt.tz_localize(None)
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
```

I get a timestamp of somewhen on the 1st of January 1970. I think, this is due to an incorrect unit. How can I amend my code to get the actual date?

Comment: The default unit is nanoseconds, but you could input `unit='s'` to use seconds instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this works. I tried: `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],utc=True,unit='s').dt.tz_localize(None)` which did not work.

Comment: weird, `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], utc=True, unit='s').dt.tz_localize(None)` works for me :)